# Finding the bound of a table element and exporting the table into a collection in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I'm trying to capture a table element of a web application. This element is a search result. I want to browse through rows and select a particular row item from the searched results.

I can use dynamic path concept to navigate through the table element. This way i can read the contents. However, how can i get the upper bounds for the captured table. Say, the number of rows and columns of the table element. and export the table into a collection

Answer (score 0):

**To read the table to the collection**

1. Spy the Table in Application Modeler.
2. Place box "Read" - use element table from previous steps, Set Data as "Get Table", choose where to store the data.

As you see, the Blue Prism is pretty well designed in regards of interacting with the hmtl tables.

**To read amount of rows**

1. Read the table to collection
2. Use Action "Count Rows" from standard Blue Prism "Collections" object.

**To read amount of columns**

1. Read the table to collection
2. Use Action "Count Columns" from standard Blue Prism "Collections" object.

Comment: Under collecltion

Comment: Under "collecltion manipulation" standard BP object.. , I'm NT finding "count rows" and "count columns" action

Comment: It's Internal Business Object, it's not the Utility. It's the most basic one like "Credentials", or "Work queues".

If you add new action, then it's at the end of the list of all business objects.

Comment: Hi. just posted another rpa table related question. Hope that you could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239664/set-html-table-header-as-rpa-collection-header