# Set html table header as rpa collection header

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Ive managed to get html table and change it to collection. However i would like for the table header to become the collection header. Is it possible to do it? Thanks.

Below is for further details on how i take the table element and change it to collection.

The path that im getting from the html table inside application modeller:

/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(2)/FORM(2)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)

Then i use Read stage and choose the table as the element and set Data as Get Table function and save the collection.

The collection result produces:

On header - Column1(text), Column2(text)....

First Row - Department, Name.... || This supposed to be the header

Second Row - DepartmentData, NameData....

Comment: You haven't provided enough information or a test case of what you're trying to read. It depends heavily on the source system and how the HTML is being output to your browser.

Comment: @esqew Hi, i just updated the question on how i get the table and change it to collection. You could assume that it is a very simple table using Table tag and simple data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got the action called "Set Column Names From First Row" in Utility - Collection Manipulation. Do you have it too?

If not, then here's the code:

```
Dim iThisColumn as integer = -1
For Each Column As DataColumn In Input_Collection.Columns
   iThisColumn +=1
   Column.ColumnName=CStr(Input_Collection.Rows.Item(0).Item(iThisColumn))
Next
Output_Collection = Input_Collection
```

[image]

Comment: Oo yes.. Just found out the action. Still new on RPA. Tqvm for your answer.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry to disturb. Just wanna ask, is there a way to get Internet explorer Process ID when we first run it? Im a bit at lost as theres not much reference to refers to when it comes to RPA blueprism. At first i was thinking of using chrome but realised that RPA is not 100% compatible with chrome. So im stuck with IE. Do tell if u need me to open this as a new question. Thanks

Comment: I guess you can do it using some coding stages, but I've never done that. Why you need PID?

Comment: Im passing data between 2 websites. So during reattach, i need to specify the process name and PID. Not sure if RPA is able to do multiple tabs.

Comment: Can't you just have two websites open at the same time?

Comment: Sometimes it gets detached. Another thing is that i was planning to bring the interacted browser to the front. Any idea on this? ( Bringing browser to the front)

Comment: Detaching shouldn't happen that often. You can use action "activate"  if you spy the windows in application mode (not as html).

Comment: ooo Tqvm. Managed to do it now. Thanks again.